# Postgres Column with Multiple Values

Tags: postgresql

I recently took over a database as admin and am unfamiliar with the columns structure in one of the tables. I would really like to know how to select one of the values in the column, as of now I can not build a where clause using this column. The column in question is the state column, I can use any of the other columns in a where clause.

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------------
id         | 8

name       | 13

state      | ---                       +
           | :name: California         +
           | :abbr: CA                 +
           | 

created_at | 2011-12-08 04:31:15.104002

updated_at | 2011-12-08 04:31:15.104002
```

Answer (score 0):

A column can't contain multiple values, but a text column can contain values with multiple lines, separated by a linefeed, or a linefeed and carriage return. The `state` column from the question has such a value, with linefeeds apparently.

If you had to inject that content back in SQL form, this may work (unless there are additional non-visible spaces):

```
select * from table where state = E'---\n:name: California\n:abbr: CA\n';
```

`\n` represents a linefeed in a string enclosed by `E'...'`, .
(see "String Constants with C-Style Escapes" in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html))